# A misunderstood part at AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs

I found a angularJS thi code at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/7/). There are two directives called uiFoo and uiBar. When I compare those two directives I couldn't find a difference. However, when I run the code, the div with the directive uiFoo does not make a difference at the html output.

The ui-foo div is initially:

```
<div ui-foo>I should change iamfoo</div>
```

When the code is run, result(output html) is also

```
I should change iamfoo
```

The ui-bar div is initially:

```
<div ui-bar>I should change iambar</div>
```

However, when the code is run, result(output html) is

```
iambar
```

What makes this difference? What am I missing?

Thanks anyway... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original directives were broken, the first was not being called as the second was overriding it due to re-defining the module.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/588/).

When you reuse the same module, you should only pass the dependencies once, like so:

```
angular.module('my.module', []);
angular.module('my.module').directive(...);
angular.module('my.module').directive(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second module definition is overwriting your first. So after its overwritten, the first directive is no longer defined.

To fix this, just use the module method for uiBar without the second parameter:

```
 angular.module('ui.directives').directive('uiBar', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the directives module is being defined twice.

`angular.module('ui.directives', [])` defines the module
`angular.module('ui.directives')` uses the module

http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/587/